# fetching details of installed apps on android device ..not able to get the permissions required for each App installed on device?

Tags: android

My code to get the permissions (required by installed apps) and other 
details for Apps installed on android device, but it is not working:

```
private void populateWithInitialApps() {
       /* StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();
        String[] requestedPermissions =  new String[]{};*/
        //  List<ApplicationInfo> appList = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
     // String name =  pm.getApplicationLabel(appList.get(0)).toString();
            //AppItem appItem = new AppItem(appList.get(0).packageName.toString(), appList.get(0).packageName.toString());
        String requestedPermissions1 ;
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfApps; i++) {
                StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();
              String per=  appList.get(0).permission;
                String[] requestedPermissions= new String[]{};
              requestedPermissions1 ="" ;
                try {
                    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(appList.get(i).packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
                     ; ;/*packageInfo.requestedPermissions;*/
                  //  if (requestedPermission1s != null) {
                 //   requestedPermissions =  new String[]{};
                       // int j = 0 ;
                    requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
                   Log.v("lentth",String.valueOf(requestedPermissions.length));
                    for (int j = 0; j < requestedPermissions.length; j++) {

                        //            appNameAndPermissions=new StringBuffer();
                            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[j]);
                            appNameAndPermissions.append(requestedPermissions[j] + "\n");


                        }
                /*    while (j<requestedPermissions.length)
                    {
                        Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[j]);
                        requestedPermissions1.concat("  "+requestedPermissions[j]);
                        j++ ;
                    }*/
                    //}
                }
                catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
                {

                }

                itemList.add( new AppItem(appList.get(i).packageName.toString(),requestedPermissions1,String.valueOf(appList.get(0).targetSdkVersion),
                        pm.getApplicationLabel(appList.get(i)).toString()));

            }

    }
```

Returns following error:

> requestPermission.length
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: Not all apps request permissions, and you need to be able to handle that in your code.

Comment: But if I handle null pointer then it gives no data still

Comment: Again, not all apps request permissions.

Comment: Yes but not for all...for YouTube it is showing no permission s...this is not possible....for all installed apps it showing blank

Comment: Bdw I have initialised request permission object .....so null pointer should not arise logically...it should give blank string

Comment: Now I Understood the logic to catch Nullpointer Exception ...but I am not getting correct results .

Comment: Help will be appreciated